# Why does this function has this property?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $f \in C^1(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{R})$ and suppose that there exist $C, r \in \Bbb{R}$, with $2 < r < 2^* = 6$, such that 
$$
|f(t)| \leq C(1+|t|^{r-1})
$$ 
Assume also that 
$$
\lim_{|t| \to 0}\frac{|f(t)|}{|t|} = 0.
$$

Then, given $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $C_{\varepsilon}$ such that $|f(t)| \leq \varepsilon |t| + C_{\varepsilon}|t|^{r-1}$.

Why is this true?

This is a claim in a text (in Portuguese) I am reading on the method of the Nehari manifold for elliptic equations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(t)/t\to0$ as $t\to0$, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
|f(t)|<\varepsilon|t|
\qquad\textrm{whenever}\quad
|t|<\delta.
$$
To proceed further, let
$$
C_\varepsilon=C(1+\delta^{1-r}),
$$
which ensures that 
$$
C(1+t^{r-1})\leq C_\varepsilon t^{r-1}
\qquad\textrm{for}\,\,t\geq\delta.
$$
Thus
$$
|f(t)|\leq\varepsilon|t|+C_\varepsilon|t|^{r-1}
\qquad\textrm{for}\,\,t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: You just need to see that two sides are equal at $t=\delta$, and the derivative of the RHS is larger than that of the LHS, because $C_\varepsilon>C$.

Comment: I messed with the exponents, I apologize. Let me redo my computations

Comment: Got this. Many thanks